# Difference between two rows in MySQL Workbench, but LAG is not authorized

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, window-functions

I have a dataset as in this example :

```
id | product_id  |        date       |  weight
1  |    454      |2019-06-26 16:08:45|   900
2  |    454      |2019-06-27 13:24:16|   900
3  |    454      |2019-06-28 10:53:42|   899
4  |    352      |2018-04-18 10:53:42|   124
5  |    352      |2018-04-19 15:26:51|   124
6  |    112      |2019-12-08 11:44:01|   065
7  |    375      |2020-03-15 08:23:43|   483
8  |    375      |2020-03-15 18:07:33|   496
9  |    375      |2020-03-16 14:32:24|   496
```

And I would like to get only the rows that have a weight different from the previous one or different from the next one. In the case of the example the expected output is :

```
id | product_id  |        date       |  weight
2  |    454      |2019-06-27 13:24:16|   900
3  |    454      |2019-06-28 10:53:42|   899
7  |    375      |2020-03-15 08:23:43|   483
8  |    375      |2020-03-15 18:07:33|   496
```

However, I have only reading permissions on this database, so the `LAG()` function does not work. What other options do I have?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.weight
              from t t2
              where t2.product_id = t.product_id and t2.date < t.date
              order by t2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_weight,
             (select t2.weight
              from t t2
              where t2.product_id = t.product_id and t2.date > t.date
              order by t2.date asc
              limit 1
             ) as next_weight
      from t
     ) t
where prev_weight <> weight or next_weight <> weight;
```

Comment: it is very very helpful! I did it in another query!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM table t2
              WHERE t1.weight <> t2.weight
              AND   t1.product_id = t2.product_id
             )
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it with a temporary variable! But I think that what you did will also work!!

Comment: @LucasMatosMolter . . . This does *not* consider whether the rows are adjacent.  For instance, it will return `id = 1`, even though `id = 2` has the same weight.